# total number of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, math-software, extremal-combinatorics

Patient Age  --->          Avg Visits / Year

<1 year       --->            7.5

1-4 years     --->            3.0

5-14 years    --->          1.8

15-24 years   --->          1.7

25-44 years   --->          2.6

45-64 years   --->          4.0

65-74 years    --->         6.7

> 75 years      --->        8.2

The table above breaks out, by age range, the average number of visits people make to physicians each year. If you were an insurance company that wanted a member mix that would average 50 physician visits per year, you could sign up either of the following two member mixes:
10 members in the "1-4 years" age range and 5 members in the "45-64 years" age range resulting in (10 x 3.0) + (5 x 4.0) = 50

2 members in the "<1 year" age range, 10 members in the "5-14 years" age range and 10 members in the "15-24 years" age range resulting in (2 x 7.5) + (10 x 1.8) + (10 x 1.7) = 50

Note that there are many more possibilities.

Question 1: What is the total number of different member mixes that result in 50 physician visits per year?

Comment: My guess would be $3071$

Comment: Is there any formula to find the coefficient for x power 50?

Answer (score 0):

Take the co-efficient of $x^{50}$ in the expansion of

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^{1.7})(1-x^{1.8})(1-x^{2.6})(1-x^{3.0})(1-x^{4.0})(1-x^{6.7})(1-x^{7.5})(1-x^{8.2})}$$

or if you prefer working with integers then remove the decimal points and take the co-efficient of $x^{500}$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know .

Comment: do we have a formula to find the coefficient of x^50 in the expression?(a+b)^n ncr a^(n-r)b^r